# Generic function to test the performance of any delegate

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, lambda

When testing the relative performance of different method implementations I find myself re-writing functions similar to this.

```
private static long Measure(
    int iterations,
    Func<string, string> func,
    string someParameter)
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        func(someParameter);
    }

    stopwatch.Stop();
    return stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
}
```

Rather than rewriting this function for every method singnature that I test, would it be possible to write a generic implementation for performance testing any delagate? Something along the lines of

```
    private static long Measure(
    int iterations,
    Delegate func,
    params object[] parameters)
{
    ...
}
```

or

```
    private static long Measure<TDelegate>(
    int iterations,
    TDelegate func,
    params object[] parameters)
{
    if (!typeof(TDelegate).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Delegate)))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Not a delegate", "func");
    }

    ...
}
```

If I can do this would it make sense to [`Compile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362.aspx) an [`Expression<TDelegate>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx) before performing the iterations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use an Action and you can set the parameters in a lambda.

```
private static long Measure(int iterations, Action action)
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        action();
    }

    stopwatch.Stop();
    return stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
}
```

Then you call it like

```
Measure(100, () => MyMethod(arg1,arg2,...));
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me to understand.

Comment: +1 To eliminate JIT issues I would call `action();` once, before starting the timer.

Comment: The downside here, is that the lamda function for contriving the call becomes part of the test. However, I see no way to overcome this with any alternative. There will always be an element of plumbing involved.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use an anonymous function to pass the parameters:

```
var p1 = ..
var p2 = ..
var p3 = ..
var p4 = ..
var p5 = ..
Measure(1000, (x) => MyTestFunc(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5), str);
```

Comment: So, what type is the second parameter of `Measure`?

Comment: Assuming the return type of `MyTestFunc` is `string`, and `x` is `string`, then `(x) => MyTestFunc(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)` is of type `Func<string, string>`.  Although, in this case, neither the input `string` parameter nor the return value are actually used anywhere - they're just there to satisfy the parameter type to `Measure`.  If you don't need them, then just use an `Action` as suggested by @juharr.

Comment: I see what your are saying now

Comment: The downside here, is that the lamda function for contriving the call becomes part of the test. However, I see no way to overcome this with any alternative.

Comment: @Jodrell: Yes.  However, as with all time testing, you are testing relative performance.  If you test method 1 vs. method 2 using the same testing harness, you should be able to accurately determine which method is "faster".  If you really are trying to time 100,000 iterations of a method that takes a few milliseconds each time (where the lamdba might have an appreciable effect on the time), I would quicker check whether you're falling prey to the danger of premature optimization.